# Update sharepoint list item with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Environment: SharePoint 365 with Power Apps and Power Automate.
I have a Power Automate that starts when a new item is created or modified.  The next step, 'Start and wait for an approval', sends an email for the user to look at the entry and Acknowledge or Decline. Then I have a Switch to check the response.  If it is Acknowledge, it send an email to say it's been acknowledged, get item step (to get the ID of the entry) and Update Item step (to set the SharePoint list field 'feedback'='Acknowledge)
But now the Power Automate sees it that the item is updated and then restarts the flow. (because I update feedback=Acknowledge)
I'm a bit new to Power Automate, maybe there is a way to eliminate this loop or another step to use to update the item?

Comment: If it's already set to start an approval process on "item created", do you also need a re-approval process if the item is edited later on?  Can you simplify the whole thing by just using a trigger when an item is created (only, and not also updated)?

Comment: The flow runs when equipment is issued to someone.  The receiver should acknowledge the equipment received.  If the issuer changes the already received equipment's description or serial number, the receiver should be notified that it changed.  So I do need a trigger when the item is changed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this but here is one approach.
Add an Approved Date field to the list.
When you are updating the feedback field, also update the Approved Date to Now().
Update the Flow to only run if the Approved Date is null.

If you don't want to use Approved Date, replace it with a Yes/No field, but the same basic logic applies.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to change the flow trigger to just "on created" if thats not possible
Create 2 different flows.

1. That checks if the Approval is acknowledged
2. That updates the item

Add condition in 1st flow to check if approval was acknowledged. If Yes trigger flow 2 else just do other stuff.